# Were the Valar aware of the surviving Balrogs? And if they weren´t but was made aware would they have removed it themselves?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, valar, balrogs

In the council of Elrond it is debated whether or not to send the ring across the ocean and transport it to Valinor.
That idea is however quickly rejected as it is mentioned that they would not receive it, as the Ring was part of middleearth and thus for the races that dwelled there to take care of.

But what about the Balrog/Balrogs?
Where the Valar aware of them?
If they weren´t but was made aware, would they once again have traveled to Middle Earth to remove them?
Or do they consider the problem of the surviving Balrogs, to be in the same league as that Ring and Sauron.
Something that the men, elves and Dwarfs of Middle Earth must take care of themselves, as the Valar will not interfere directly in the affairs of Middle Earth again?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108236/did-any-other-balrogs-survive-into-the-third-age

Comment: The hosts of Valinor are not going to come to help with Sauron, so why would they come for any lesser maiar?

Comment: The Balrog was not the kind of existential threat that Morgoth posed to the Children of Eru. Nobody in Middle Earth really *needed* to "take care of" the Balrog; they simply needed to not poke it, metaphorically speaking. (Nobody new about it for ~5,000 years after Morgoth's defeat, and even then it never left Moria.) For *story* purposes, one can probably assume the one in Moria *was* the last remaining one, and Gandalf took care of it, unintentionally clearing the slate for the upcoming Dominion of Men.